# InvalidArgumentException in SQLiteConnector.php: Database (storage/database.sqlite) does not exist

Tags: database, sqlite, laravel, exception

I recently started exploring Laravel and I am aiming to build a simple website with basic CRUD functionalities. So the context here is that I want to be able to display a list of all entries within a page, but when I create that index page I am met with the following exception:

```
    InvalidArgumentException in SQLiteConnector.php line 34:
    Database (storage/database.sqlite) does not exist.
    in SQLiteConnector.php line 34
    at SQLiteConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'sqlite', 'database' => 'storage/database.sqlite', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlite')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 61
    at ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
    at call_user_func(object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 868
    at Connection->getPdo() in Connection.php line 736
    at Connection->reconnectIfMissingConnection() in Connection.php line 621
    at Connection->run('select * from "certificates"', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 342
    at Connection->select('select * from "certificates"', array(), true) in Builder.php line 1515
    at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1501
    at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 596
    at Builder->getModels(array('*')) in Builder.php line 303
    at Builder->get(array('*')) in Model.php line 646
    at Model::all() in certificatesController.php line 15
    at CertificatesController->index()
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CertificatesController), 'index'), array()) in Controller.php line 80
    at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
    at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(CertificatesController), object(Route), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
    at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
    at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(CertificatesController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\certificatesController', 'index') in Route.php line 174
    at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in         ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

The solutions to similar questions asked on Stackoverflow didn't work for me. Basically, these are what are in my .env and config/database.php files right now:

**.env**

```
    DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=8888
    DB_DATABASE=storage/database.sqlite
```

**config/database.php**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),
'sqlite' => [
             'driver' => 'sqlite',
             'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            ],
```

I'm running this locally (not Homestead) and I've been trying to change the different values several times (e.g. using an absolute path, switching port numbers between 3306 and 8888). Will really appreciate if someone can offer some advice on how to solve this :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that there's no `storage/database.sqlite` please make sure that you create a empty text file in the storage folder and name it `database.sqlite` and then run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: I do have the `storage/database.sqlite` file already and when I run `php artisan migrate` I get the following message: "Nothing to migrate". When I run `sqlite3 storage/database.sqlite` on Terminal, it's working fine as well. Any other reason why this problem might have occurred?

Comment: did you run `chmod -R o+w storage`?